# Unintended Hyperlink in Email Subject line

Tags: email, outlook

I've written some code that generates e-mails and sends them via a .Net program. My local environment uses Lotus Notes but the QA team use Outlook. They've got a bug which I cannot recreate.

So the e-mail subject line is:

"CLI-ABC File:Modified_Member_Enroll blah blah blah"

In the QA tester's Outlook the 'File:Modified_Member_Enroll' is a hyperlink which is not intended. In Lotus Notes this isn't the case.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Is it because I have 'File:' and this means something to Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything you can do. The RTF edit control used to show the subject looks for the known protocol prefixes (http:, https:, file:, etc.).

Comment: What if I remove the string "File:" from the subject?

Comment: Or even just the colon :